# Python AsyncHttpClient inside tornado RequestHandler throws exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, tornado

I'm going to call an endpoint by tornado AsyncHttpClient in RequestHandler, but it throws runtime exception `This event loop is already running`

```
class RegistrationHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

  def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
      call_async_register("some params")


def call_async_register(parameters):
    def call():
        http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
        future = Future()
        http_request = HTTPRequest(url, request_type.name, headers={'X-Peering': '1'}, body=body)

        def handle_future(f: Future):
            future.set_result(f.result())

        fetched_future = http_client.fetch(http_request)

        fetched_future.add_done_callback(handle_future)

        return future
    try:
        instance = io_loop.IOLoop.current()
        response = instance.run_sync(call)
        return response.body.decode()
    except Exception as err:
        self.logger.exception("Account Request Failed: {}".format(err))
        return None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
instance = io_loop.IOLoop.current()
response = instance.run_sync(call)
```

`run_sync` itself tries to start the ioloop. But as apparent from your code, `instance` is already running. So you get the error.

If you want to send the value returned by `call()` method back to the user, convert your methods to coroutines (use `async/await` syntax).

Example:

```
class RegistrationHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    async def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        response = await call_async_register("some params")

        self.write(response)


async def call_async_register(parameters):
    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    http_request = HTTPRequest(url, request_type.name, headers={'X-Peering': '1'}, body=body)

    try:
        response = await http_client.fetch(http_request)
        return response.body.decode()
    except Exception as err:
        self.logger.exception("Account Request Failed: {}".format(err))
        return None
```

Comment: @SuperHornet Do you want to return the result of `call()` back to the client?

Comment: Yes I do want to return reponse